# BIOS setting disappeared after installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, hardware, bootloader, bios

I was trying to install ubuntu on my laptop(which is old and doesn't support UEFI) and while installing, it showed this error message:
"The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install target/".

I found the solution(here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1044751) and it solved the problem with the error, installation finished then the computer got restarted but ubuntu didn't started, to be clear nothing happened except that this page shows right after turning on the laptop:
[Bios setting problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcFHg.jpg)

Now I can't even access my "bios settings" page neither using a bootable memory.

While I hit F2 during the hardware initialization the same page keeps showing. When I'm in the page and press Enter the page just loads again, what should I do?

Comment: There is no way for the operating system to affect the functioning of the BIOS menu. Provide more information about your hardware please?

Comment: @AmithKK it's fujitsu AH532, Intel core i5 Sandy bridge CPU, and 12 GB of ram

Comment: What happens when you press tab on the screen that comes up?

Comment: @AmithKK it switches to "Application Menu" tab, there's one option "Diagnostic Screen"

Comment: @AmithKK It shows my hdd and cdrom model no.

Comment: Actually, the OS can change the BIOS.  There was a bug filed https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147 that would corrupt the BIOS from 17.10

Comment: @Terrance Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I think in the bug filing there was some steps to try.   But I am not 100% sure as I don't have a UEFI system to test this on.  What you're experiencing might be a new bug.  See if the manufacturer of your system might have a BIOS reset or recovery procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Upon looking up the Laptop Model on Google, several issues with your specific model of laptop losing BIOS usability(Albeit on windows installs) popped up

The solution seems to be unplugging the hard drive, which will allow the bios to work, going to "Advanced Settings" and disabling FastBoot

[Source](https://forum.ts.fujitsu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=46501)

Comment: I removed the hard disc and nothing changed, still the same page keeps showing.