# UEFI boot fails after Ubuntu 18.04 kernel update

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

Did a *apt dist-update* on Ubuntu 18.04 couple of days ago. The system is stuck on grub prompt since then.

Have attempted to resolve this by booting into Ubuntu Live DVD, mounting and chroot'ing into the system to reinstall grub by *grub-install --no-nvram --root-directory=/; update-grub*. There are no errors printed. Also tried reinstalling grub-efi-amd64 and grub-efi-amd64-signed packages. Again, no errors.

Also followed the steps outlined here without any luck. [The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install target/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028703/the-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install-target)

Ubuntu is the only OS installed on this system.

My next step is to try using the boot-repair utility to try and get the system back.

Any ideas on what is causing this? That would help me understand on how I can resolve this and/or to prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: Boot repair is best plan. If not fixed then post link to Boot repair log here. In meantime I'm declining system updates until we figure this out

Comment: The 18.04 gui update just crashed with a message about a kernel (?) not there to remove. Command line only updated all the other files that were in list of updates, but nothing about any kernels to add or remove.

Comment: Boot-repair was not able to fix the issue. Boot-repair logs are at http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/fY3H6fsRHw/.

Comment: My 18.04 systems got a new kernel on 8/7. Version 4.15.0-30. I didn't have any issues with the update.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: are you booting using MBR or UEFI?

Comment: I have one UEFI system with Secure Boot disabled. All the rest are BIOS.

Comment: Running boot-repair the third got the system up, for now. I wish I knew what caused it to get gummed up in the first place. I do not want to be doing this after every dist-update. Will try and get lucky finding the root-cause needle in the haystack.