# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installer crashed halfway during the installation

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, crash

I was trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS alongside Windows 10 when it crashed halfway during the installation saying that it was unable to install the grub. After closing it and opening Windows 10, I found that a new partition had been created. Now what should I do to that partition and how should I install it again?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit of a shot in the dark but I can only think of 3 reasons why grub wouldn't install (in the order I think would be mostly likely):

1. The BIOS is protecting the MBR (master boot record) from being written
2. The boot section of the hard drive is corrupted (less likely since Windows boots)
3. grub on the installation media is corrupted

If you try installing again, are you able to install grub on the new partition instead of the MBR? (you will see an option for that at the end of the installation process). If so, then that eliminates #2 and #3 and points to #1.

Comment: When i am installing, should i go for the "boot along side windows 10" option or the "something else" option?

Comment: "boot along side window 10" if you want to be able to multiboot.

Comment: When will I be able to choose the disk parition?

Comment: I think it's the last prompt, just after the installation but before the reboot.

Comment: Do I have to create swap partition and root partitions separately if so?

Comment: If you want a swap partition, then yes it has to be separate from the boot partition - and make it small - a gig or so. If you have a good bit of RAM (say 4G or more), you might not even need the swap - unless you run something that uses more memory than usual.

Comment: It is saying that Ubuntu 18.04 is already installed and asking if I would I like to erase it and reinstall. What should I do?

Comment: If this is a brand new install you're doing (and it sounds like it is), then just erase and reinstall to start clean. Beware that if this is not a new install and you had data on the Linux partition it will be erased.

Comment: It is automatically installing in that same previous partition. So it is not a problem right?

Comment: Correct. Not a problem.

Comment: Again the grub package failed to load..It says "The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/. Without the GRUB boot loader, the installed system will not boot."

Comment: Check this out: I think it describes the same thing that that's going on with your system and it has a good solution to it:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028703/the-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install-target

Comment: Did you solve the problem?