# Ubuntu 18.04 installation issues (GRUB installation failed)

Tags: 18.04, grub2

I am inquiring about the problem of installing Ubuntu 18.04. GRUB installation failed problem occurs. When Ubuntu 18.04 is installed on the other 3 PCs, it will be installed immediately without any problems. What's the problem?

This is a list of hardware.

Mainboard: ASUS, Q470EA-IM-A 1 EA
  CPU: Intel, i9-10900K 1 EA
  RAM: Samsung, DDR4 8GB PC4-25600 2 EA
  SSD: Samsung, 970 Pro 512GB M.2 NVMe MLC 1 EA

[image]

Comment: Hello, why do you want to install 18.04 and not 22.04? How did you try to install Ubuntu? Is it Dual-Boot with Windows or only Ubuntu? What does it mean “the Grub installation failed, problem occurs”, which problem? Do you have an error in the installer? Is it only at reboot? Etc... you need to specify your problem, otherwise it is very difficult to help

Comment: 1. The program to be installed only in 18.04
It will be executed.
2. Install Ubuntu 18.04 only.
3.Error will occur during installation.
4.Attempting to install with USB image.

Comment: Sorry I didn’t see the picture you attached. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028703/the-grub-efi-amd64-signed-package-failed-to-install-target does the most upvoted solution of this Thread help?